# Relative Linking with React-Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How do we do it? Especially when part of the path is a param (:someParam). I can't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: Can you explain a bit better? Give an example.

Comment: Thanks anyway, there's a package for it. https://github.com/ryanflorence/react-router-relative-links.

Answer (score 0):

It's now recommended to use react-router 3 for this scenario
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3325

For anyone having this problem with react-router 2.x:

You may use browserHistory to support relative routes, instead of using the Link component.

```
    // assuming http://site/myanimals

    // configure router for hosting in subdirectory
    const history = useRouterHistory(createHistory)({
       basename: '/myanimals'
    });

    // then use it ...
    import {browserHistory} from 'react-router';

    browserHistory.push('about');

    // or, for a configured route with 'animal/:id' you can use 

    // <Route path={'animal:id'} .../>           
    browserHistory.push('animal/3');
```

I hope this helps!