# Programmatic relative links with react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Did somebody manage to find a good way how to programmatically navigate to a relative link with react-router?

I've used [react-router-relative-links](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-relative-links) for declarative links, but I can't find a good way to do this programmatically.

I know it could be done manually with [resolve-pathname](https://www.npmjs.com/package/resolve-pathname) and `router.push(…)`, but that would require access to the `location`, which is only available on route handler components. My component is somewhat deep down the tree, therefore I'd like to avoid all the wiring back to the top.

Is `window.location.pathname` the right way to get the location and then use `router.push` available through `withRouter`?

Currently I'm using this as a utility function:

```
import resolvePathname from 'resolve-pathname';

function getPathnameFromRelativeLocation(relativeLocation) {
  let {pathname} = window.location;
  let basePath = pathname.endsWith('/') ? pathname : pathname + '/';
  return resolvePathname(relativeLocation, basePath);
}
```

And in an event handler of a React component:

```
// Current path is `/books/123`
let path = getPathnameFromRelativeLocation('write-review');
this.props.router.push(path);
// Current path is `/books/123/write-review`
```

Comment: Do you have an example of what you're trying to do? E.g. "take the current route, add something, navigate, push to history".

Comment: Cool. That's close to what I do. I get the current from `location` and update the URL with `browserHistory.push()` because you can get at it anywhere. If you're just appending the URL you could do `location.pathname.replace(/\/$/, '') + '/newPath'` or something, unless you're doing fancier relative relationships than that.

Comment: For react-router 2.x see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37428723/relative-linking-with-react-router/40635647#40635647

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`react-router` 3.0 now provides `location` on the context so it's now easy to just take it from there.

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3325

Answer (score 0):

if you are using browserHistory
 it's simply

```
browserHistory.push('/yourRelativePath');
```

for that make sure you have latest react-router and

```
 import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
```

Comment: That's an absolute link, right? And why would you use `browserHistory.push` instead of `router.push`?

Comment: `browserHistory` is what they reference [in the docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/0625e7656d21863563cf59019cfc16b800b79e85/docs/guides/NavigatingOutsideOfComponents.md)

Comment: @amann Nope, that's a relative path. I am not aware of  `router.push` can you provide a link. Routing in web app is not only about navigation only, it also includes history management. Out of 3 history from react-router browserHistory provides native history API like feature. You can check the link given by @David Gilbertson.

Comment: Hm, it's not really working for me. I guess I'll stick with `router.push` for now, as that will also work server-side. Also as I'm changing the location from a component, `router` seems to be the way to go (`browserHistory` only for navigation outside of components as the docs say). Here are the docs for `router.push` btw: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#pushpathorloc